# AngularJS - directive only firing on one of many uses

Tags: angularjs

The goal is that, when an element gets close to the top of a page, it applies a class to a nav item.

**TEMPLATE**

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#someID">Some ID</a>
  </li>
</ul>
 ...

<div id="someId" hightlight-relevant-items></div>
```

**DIRECTIVE**

```
'use strict';

angular.module("common.directives")
    .directive('highlightRelevantItems', function () {
        return function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.detectPos = function () {
                var distanceScrolled = $(window).scrollTop();

                var topOfElement = element.offset().top;
                var height = element.height();
                var link = '[href="#' + element.attr('id') + '"]';
                var delta = topOfElement - distanceScrolled;
                var offScreen = delta+height

                if (delta < 0 && offScreen > 0) {
                    $(link).addClass('active');
                } else if (delta >= 0) {
                    $(link).removeClass('active');
                } else if (offScreen <= 0) {
                    $(link).removeClass('active');
                }
                console.log(element.attr('id') + ' ' + topOfElement);

            }

            $(window).bind('scroll', function () {

                scope.detectPos();
            });

        }
    });
```

Right now, this directive fires for all the elements with the directive attribute, but only registers to the last interation.  So if I had `someID1`, `someID2`, `someID3`, it will fire for all elements, but only with data for `someID3`.

How do I get it to work for all elements using the directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an isolated scope for each instance of the directive. Like this:

```js
angular.module("common.directives")
    .directive('highlightRelevantItems', function() {

        return {
          scope: {
            detectPos: '&'
          },
          link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.detectPos = function() {
                var distanceScrolled = $(window).scrollTop();

                var topOfElement = element.offset().top;
                var height = element.height();
                var link = '[href="#' + element.attr('id') + '"]';
                var delta = topOfElement - distanceScrolled;
                var offScreen = delta + height

                if (delta < 0 && offScreen > 0) {
                    $(link).addClass('active');
                } else if (delta >= 0) {
                    $(link).removeClass('active');
                } else if (offScreen <= 0) {
                    $(link).removeClass('active');
                }
                console.log(element.attr('id') + ' ' + topOfElement);

            }

            $(window).bind('scroll', function() {

                scope.detectPos();
            });

          }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I had looked at this method, but couldn't figure out where to put my window scroll bind.  Many thanks.

Comment: create a separate directive for that, and use the directive in the body tag or a root div tag, since it should only be trigger once

Answer (score 1):

Your directive uses its parent's scope. This means that you're **overwriting** `scope.detectPos` each time the directive gets initialized. That's why it gets called once and only for the last element, `someID3`.

A quick fix would be not to bind `detectPos` to scope and just declare it as a function:

```
angular
  .module('common.directives')
  .directive('highlightRelevantItems', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {

      var detectPos = function() {
        var distanceScrolled = $(window).scrollTop();

        var topOfElement = element.offset().top;
        var height = element.height();
        var link = '[href="#' + element.attr('id') + '"]';
        var delta = topOfElement - distanceScrolled;
        var offScreen = delta + height

        if (delta < 0 && offScreen > 0) {
          $(link).addClass('active');
        } else if (delta >= 0) {
          $(link).removeClass('active');
        } else if (offScreen <= 0) {
          $(link).removeClass('active');
        }

        console.log(element.attr('id') + ' ' + topOfElement);
      }

      $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        detectPos();
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: I tried doing `dir= this;` but it came back `ctrl` is undefined.  Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: I don't understant what you're saying... I've also attached a code example.